# Pipe Model not working properly in openmodelica

Tags: fluid, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

so this question is following another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383343/does-this-openmodelica-model-make-sense-in-a-physical-point-of-view/71403444?noredirect=1#comment126232831_71403444).

After looking the `DynamicPipe` model structure of the `ModelicaStandardLibrary`, I decided to use it to model a hollow fluid. Basically what I did is that I added a parameter corresponding to the outer diameter and reformulate the calculation of the area. In order to do that, instead of extending the `PartialStraigthPipe`, I rewrote it, add a new parameter and reformulate the calculation of the area. The rest is just a copy and paste of the `DynamicPipe` because the volumes are based on the area calculation. I have been careful to keep the same variable name for the area : `crossArea` because it is used in a lot of formulas.

Then I tried to use it in a model. Checking the model is not an issue but when I launch the simulation I get the following warning and the simulation stops at some percentage depending of the parameters. I don't understand the warning about the temperature as I don't declare such a temprature in my model parameters.

[image]

Below is the code for the hollow pipe model :

```
 model Hollow_Pipe
  import Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure;
  import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;
  import Modelica.Constants;
  // Geometry
  // Note: define nParallel as Real to support inverse calculations
  parameter Real nParallel(min = 1) = 1 "Number of identical parallel pipes" annotation(
    Dialog(group = "Geometry"));
  parameter SI.Length length "Length" annotation(
    Dialog(tab = "General", group = "Geometry"));
  parameter Boolean isCircular = true "= true if cross sectional area is circular" annotation(
    Evaluate,
    Dialog(tab = "General", group = "Geometry"));
  parameter SI.Diameter diameter "Inner diameter of hollow pipe" annotation(
    Dialog(group = "Geometry", enable = isCircular));
  parameter SI.Diameter DX "Outer diameter of hollow pipe";
  parameter SI.Area crossArea = pi * DX * DX / 4 - pi * diameter * diameter / 4 "Inner cross section area" annotation(
    Dialog(tab = "General", group = "Geometry", enable = not isCircular));
  parameter SI.Length perimeter(min = 0) = pi * diameter "Inner perimeter" annotation(
    Dialog(tab = "General", group = "Geometry", enable = not isCircular));
  parameter Modelica.Fluid.Types.Roughness roughness = 2.5e-5 "Average height of surface asperities (default: smooth steel pipe)" annotation(
    Dialog(group = "Geometry"));
  final parameter SI.Volume V = crossArea * length * nParallel "volume size";
  // Static head
  parameter SI.Length height_ab = 0 "Height(port_b) - Height(port_a)" annotation(
    Dialog(group = "Static head"));
  // Pressure loss
  replaceable model FlowModel = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.FlowModels.DetailedPipeFlow constrainedby Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.FlowModels.PartialStaggeredFlowModel "Wall friction, gravity, momentum flow" annotation(
     Dialog(group = "Pressure loss"),
     choicesAllMatching = true);
  // extending PartialTwoPortFlow
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.PartialTwoPortFlow(final lengths = fill(length / n, n), final crossAreas = fill(crossArea, n), final dimensions = fill(4 * crossArea / perimeter, n), final roughnesses = fill(roughness, n), final dheights = height_ab * dxs);
  // Wall heat transfer
  parameter Boolean use_HeatTransfer = false "= true to use the HeatTransfer model" annotation(
    Dialog(tab = "Assumptions", group = "Heat transfer"));
  replaceable model HeatTransfer = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.IdealFlowHeatTransfer constrainedby Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.PartialFlowHeatTransfer "Wall heat transfer" annotation(
     Dialog(tab = "Assumptions", group = "Heat transfer", enable = use_HeatTransfer),
     choicesAllMatching = true);
  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.HeatPorts_a[nNodes] heatPorts if use_HeatTransfer annotation(
    Placement(transformation(extent = {{-10, 45}, {10, 65}}), iconTransformation(extent = {{-30, 36}, {32, 52}})));
  HeatTransfer heatTransfer(redeclare final package Medium = Medium, final n = n, final nParallel = nParallel, final surfaceAreas = perimeter * lengths, final lengths = lengths, final dimensions = dimensions, final roughnesses = roughnesses, final states = mediums.state, final vs = vs, final use_k = use_HeatTransfer) "Heat transfer model" annotation(
    Placement(transformation(extent = {{-45, 20}, {-23, 42}})));
  final parameter Real[n] dxs = lengths / sum(lengths);
equation
  assert(length >= height_ab, "Parameter length must be greater or equal height_ab.");
  Qb_flows = heatTransfer.Q_flows;
// Wb_flow = v*A*dpdx + v*F_fric
//         = v*A*dpdx + v*A*flowModel.dp_fg - v*A*dp_grav
  if n == 1 or useLumpedPressure then
    Wb_flows = dxs * (vs * dxs * (crossAreas * dxs) * (port_b.p - port_a.p + sum(flowModel.dps_fg) - system.g * (dheights * mediums.d))) * nParallel;
  else
    if modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_vb or modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_b then
      Wb_flows[2:n - 1] = {vs[i] * crossAreas[i] * ((mediums[i + 1].p - mediums[i - 1].p) / 2 + (flowModel.dps_fg[i - 1] + flowModel.dps_fg[i]) / 2 - system.g * dheights[i] * mediums[i].d) for i in 2:n - 1} * nParallel;
    else
      Wb_flows[2:n - 1] = {vs[i] * crossAreas[i] * ((mediums[i + 1].p - mediums[i - 1].p) / 2 + (flowModel.dps_fg[i] + flowModel.dps_fg[i + 1]) / 2 - system.g * dheights[i] * mediums[i].d) for i in 2:n - 1} * nParallel;
    end if;
    if modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_vb then
      Wb_flows[1] = vs[1] * crossAreas[1] * ((mediums[2].p - mediums[1].p) / 2 + flowModel.dps_fg[1] / 2 - system.g * dheights[1] * mediums[1].d) * nParallel;
      Wb_flows[n] = vs[n] * crossAreas[n] * ((mediums[n].p - mediums[n - 1].p) / 2 + flowModel.dps_fg[n - 1] / 2 - system.g * dheights[n] * mediums[n].d) * nParallel;
    elseif modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_b then
      Wb_flows[1] = vs[1] * crossAreas[1] * ((mediums[2].p - mediums[1].p) / 2 + flowModel.dps_fg[1] / 2 - system.g * dheights[1] * mediums[1].d) * nParallel;
      Wb_flows[n] = vs[n] * crossAreas[n] * ((port_b.p - mediums[n - 1].p) / 1.5 + flowModel.dps_fg[n - 1] / 2 + flowModel.dps_fg[n] - system.g * dheights[n] * mediums[n].d) * nParallel;
    elseif modelStructure == ModelStructure.a_vb then
      Wb_flows[1] = vs[1] * crossAreas[1] * ((mediums[2].p - port_a.p) / 1.5 + flowModel.dps_fg[1] + flowModel.dps_fg[2] / 2 - system.g * dheights[1] * mediums[1].d) * nParallel;
      Wb_flows[n] = vs[n] * crossAreas[n] * ((mediums[n].p - mediums[n - 1].p) / 2 + flowModel.dps_fg[n] / 2 - system.g * dheights[n] * mediums[n].d) * nParallel;
    elseif modelStructure == ModelStructure.a_v_b then
      Wb_flows[1] = vs[1] * crossAreas[1] * ((mediums[2].p - port_a.p) / 1.5 + flowModel.dps_fg[1] + flowModel.dps_fg[2] / 2 - system.g * dheights[1] * mediums[1].d) * nParallel;
      Wb_flows[n] = vs[n] * crossAreas[n] * ((port_b.p - mediums[n - 1].p) / 1.5 + flowModel.dps_fg[n] / 2 + flowModel.dps_fg[n + 1] - system.g * dheights[n] * mediums[n].d) * nParallel;
    else
      assert(false, "Unknown model structure");
    end if;
  end if;
  connect(heatPorts, heatTransfer.heatPorts) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, 55}, {0, 54}, {-34, 54}, {-34, 38.7}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
end Hollow_Pipe;
```

And below is the model of my system :

```
model Circuit_BT

//Define the properties of Fluid1 and Fluid2
  replaceable package Medium=Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater constrainedby
    Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;

//Define the type of heat transfer for forced convection
  replaceable model HeatTransfer_1 =
      Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.LocalPipeFlowHeatTransfer;
 
 //Define the flow for pressure loss
  replaceable model FlowModel_1 = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.FlowModels.DetailedPipeFlow;

  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system;
  
  //Definition of Fluid1
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe(redeclare package Medium = Medium, redeclare final model HeatTransfer = HeatTransfer_1, redeclare final model FlowModel = FlowModel_1, T_start = 318.15, diameter = 12.8e-3,p_a_start=14.6e5, p_b_start = 14e5, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, length = 15, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, nNodes = 10, nParallel = 1,  use_HeatTransfer = true);
  
  //Definition of Fluid2
  
 BT_test.Hollow_Pipe pipe1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, redeclare final model HeatTransfer = HeatTransfer_1, redeclare final model FlowModel = FlowModel_1, T_start = 328.15, diameter = 18.8e-3, DX=25e-3, p_b_start = 14e5, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, length = 15, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, nNodes = 10, nParallel = 1, use_HeatTransfer = true);
  
  //Define the properties of the wall of the tube of Fluid1
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger.BaseClasses.WallConstProps wallConstProps( T_start = 318.15,area_h = 0.89535390627, c_wall = 510, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, k_wall = 60.5, n = 10, rho_wall = 7850, s = 6e-3);
  
  //Inlet limit conditions for Fluid1
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary(redeclare package Medium = Medium,T=318.15, nPorts = 1, p = 14.6e5);
  
  //Outlet limit conditions for Fluid1
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, p = 14e5, nPorts = 1,use_T_in=true);
  
  //Inlet limit conditions for Fluid2
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T massflow(redeclare package
      Medium = Medium, nPorts = 1, T = 353.15, use_m_flow_in=true);
  
  //Outlet limit conditions for Fluid2
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary3(redeclare package Medium = Medium, nPorts = 1, p = 14e5,use_T_in=true);
  
  //Coupure d'injection
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp coupure(startTime=5,
    duration=2,
    height=-0.2,
    offset=0.2);
  
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sensors.TemperatureSensor sensor;
  
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sensors.TemperatureSensor sensor2;

 equation

  connect(boundary.ports[1], pipe.port_a);
  connect(pipe.port_b, boundary1.ports[1]);
  connect(massflow.ports[1], pipe1.port_a);
  connect(coupure.y, massflow.m_flow_in);
  connect(pipe1.port_b, boundary3.ports[1]);  
  connect(wallConstProps.heatPort_b, pipe.heatPorts);
  connect(pipe1.heatPorts,wallConstProps.heatPort_a);
  connect(sensor.T, boundary1.T_in);
  connect(sensor.port,pipe.heatPorts[10]);
  connect(sensor2.T,boundary3.T_in);
  connect(sensor2.port,pipe1.heatPorts[10]);

end Circuit_BT;
```

Can someone help me ?
Best regards,
Maxime